# Splunk - Handling a blank token for a dashboard search

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I have the following search for a drill down from another dashboard:

```
MY SEARCH
|eval Status = if(isnull(REASON), "Null", REASON)
|eval Time = strftime(_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
|stats values(MEM_NBR) as MEM_NBR, latest(Status) as Status, max(Time) as TIME by C_ID
|where Status="$tok_status$"
|sort limit=0 Time desc
```

The token `"$tok_status$"` will be coming from a dashboard click and is connected to a text box. My question is how do I show all the available "Status" if the token is blank?

I have tried:

```
|where Status = if(isnull("$tok_status$"), Status, "$tok_status$")
```

But that did not work.

Comment: default `$tok_status$` to `*` - so that when it is "empty", it matches "anything"

Comment: Thanks but I was trying that in dashboard studio and the ````*```` was killing the search for some reason.  Maybe I was doing something else wrong but for now the accepted answer is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe "$tok_status$" becomes "" when the token is not provided so the `isnull` function will always return false.  Try

`|where Status = if("$tok_status$"="", Status, "$tok_status$")`.
Another option is let Splunk add the quotes around the token, if it exists.

`|where Status = if(isnull($tok_status|s$), Status, "$tok_status$")`

Comment: @H22, which option worked for you?

Comment: |where Status = if("$tok_status$"="", Status, "$tok_status$")

Thank you.